# Finding total area and percentage of specific color band value from Orthomosaic?

Tags: raster, statistics, orthophoto

I want to get statistics for a color band within an orthomosaic. Specifically I want to know what area or percentage area of the raster is above a particular value.i.e. band 2 > 60. I'd like to know the simplest way to do this. I imagine this can be done in a number of ways, perhaps using python code, but I don't know how to write the few lines required. Or maybe there is a plugin?

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Depends de software? In QGIS, ArcGis, or only in phyton? 
For example in QGIS, or Grass GIS, you can uses a *i.maxlik*, this library, classifies the cell spectral reflectances in imagery data.
Classification is based on the spectral signature information generated by either i.cluster, g.gui.iclass, or i.gensig. 
Both GIS worked with pythn command line

Answer (score 1):

easiest way i can think of:
in raster calculator:

```
(band2 > 60)
```

then, measure the area of the output map with
r.stats of the grass plugin